# ErrorException Trying to get property 'locale' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Exception Error when projects run on the local.Trying to get property 'locale' of non-object error found.I really don't know what is wrong.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->global = Setting::first();
    App::setLocale($this->global->locale);
    Carbon::setLocale($this->global->locale);
    setlocale(LC_TIME,$this->global->locale.'_'.strtoupper($this->global->locale));
}
```

This code where 'locale' added.

Comment: Please provide some more context. Is there data in the `settings` table? Where is this code running? In a controller? Where is the property `global` defined? The reason you're getting that error is because `Setting::first()` is returning null. But why, is the real question.

Comment: This code is running in a Controller

Comment: No data in settings table,is that why this error is coming?

Comment: Very likely. `Setting::first()` will retrieve the first row and converts it into a model which will be `null` if there is no data. You then try to access `locale` on `null` - _Trying to get property 'locale' of non-object_

Answer (score 0):

Make `var_dump(Setting::first());die();` in your `__construct()` method